# Is it possible to import in Dataflow streaming pipeline written in Python the Java method `wrapBigQueryInsertError`?

Tags: java, python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to create a Dataflow streaming pipeline with Python3 that reads messages from a Pub/Sub topic to end up writing them on a BigQuery table "from scratch". I've seen in the Dataflow Java template named [PubSubToBigQuery.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java) (that carries out what I'm looking for) a piece of code in the 3th step to handle those Pub/Sub messages transformed into table rows that fail when you try to insert them into the BigQuery table. Finally, in the code pieces of the steps 4 and 5, those are flatten and inserted in an error table:

- Step 3:

```
PCollection<FailsafeElement<String, String>> failedInserts =
        writeResult
            .getFailedInsertsWithErr()
            .apply(
                "WrapInsertionErrors",
                MapElements.into(FAILSAFE_ELEMENT_CODER.getEncodedTypeDescriptor())
                    .via((BigQueryInsertError e) -> wrapBigQueryInsertError(e)))
            .setCoder(FAILSAFE_ELEMENT_CODER);
```

- Steps 4 & 5

```
    PCollectionList.of(
            ImmutableList.of(
                convertedTableRows.get(UDF_DEADLETTER_OUT),
                convertedTableRows.get(TRANSFORM_DEADLETTER_OUT)))
        .apply("Flatten", Flatten.pCollections())
        .apply(
            "WriteFailedRecords",
            ErrorConverters.WritePubsubMessageErrors.newBuilder()
                .setErrorRecordsTable(
                    ValueProviderUtils.maybeUseDefaultDeadletterTable(
                        options.getOutputDeadletterTable(),
                        options.getOutputTableSpec(),
                        DEFAULT_DEADLETTER_TABLE_SUFFIX))
                .setErrorRecordsTableSchema(ResourceUtils.getDeadletterTableSchemaJson())
                .build());


    failedInserts.apply(
        "WriteFailedRecords",
        ErrorConverters.WriteStringMessageErrors.newBuilder()
            .setErrorRecordsTable(
                ValueProviderUtils.maybeUseDefaultDeadletterTable(
                    options.getOutputDeadletterTable(),
                    options.getOutputTableSpec(),
                    DEFAULT_DEADLETTER_TABLE_SUFFIX))
            .setErrorRecordsTableSchema(ResourceUtils.getDeadletterTableSchemaJson())
            .build());
```

In order to do this, I suspect that the key to making this possible lies in the first imported library in the template:

```
package com.google.cloud.teleport.templates;
import static com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.TextToBigQueryStreaming.wrapBigQueryInsertError;
```

Is this method available in Python?

If not, there is some way to perform the same in Python that is not to check that the structure and the data type of fields of the records that should be inserted corresponds to what the BigQuery table expects?

This kind of workaround slows down my streaming pipeline too much.

Answer (score 1):

In Beam Python, when performing a streaming BigQuery write, the rows which failed during the BigQuery write are returned by the transform. See https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1248

So you can process these in the same way as the Java template.